# 403 - forbidden access is denied. IIS

Tags: ssl, iis, ssl-certificate, iis-8

I have hosted a site in IIS (Version 10.0.16299) on windows 10. 
My site running under SSL required. When my site running with SSL required I am getting error
**403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.**

But when I disable required SSL, I am not receiving this kind of error everything is working fine.
But in my case, it is a must to use a required SSL connection.

The IIS hosted site is a simple directory browsing site.

How can I use it with the required SSL?

And I have attached the Trace root are in the below link.

[Failed Trace root file](https://filebin.net/2obtrpu2gv9yt04d)

Comment: Most people use URL Rewrite module to write an HTTP to HTTPS redirection rule. Please consider that.

Comment: I don't use any kind of URL rewrite, I have simple application which has some directories and only web.config file, & I have used directory browsing enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a certification related issue we observed and resolved when installed the right certificate in the trusted root.

Answer (score 1):

I reviewed your FRT log and the error message is 403.7-Client certificate required.

It is obviously that you are Setting **Client certificates** to **required**. If you don't need client certificate authentication for your web application, then **Require** is not required.

If you just want to enable SSL for your https site,Check **Require SSL** and set client certificate to **ignore** is enough.

[image]

Please keep in mind that you need to Set Client Certificates to **required** only when your web app require to pass client certificate from client side

Comment: Thanks but we need to require SSL settings.

Comment: @user619 Emm have you hard code client certificate authentication? Or enable client certificate mapping? If you enable required, then you need to send a client certificate every time  when you access the website. If you just need to allow client certificate, then set it to accept is enough

Comment: In addition, if you want to force the use of "https" then you can user "URL Rewrite" to redirect all the calls to https.

Answer (score 0):

[Configuration need to change on IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBn9g.png)

Occurrence of 403 is not only particular instance, it's IIS configuration part, in most case you can resolve from IIS it's self, there might be some restriction level in IIS setting, you can check on IIS where your site hosted, find IP Address and Domain Restrictions option and check there will an entry to allow specif IP address, we need to update that entry by checking **Edit Feature Settings...** [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pa0h3.png) then need to select Access for unspecified clients: earlier may be Deny instead of this we need to allow [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKxbg.png). after those changes, your url available to access if you have same issue which I described.